# error: Multiple commands produce `/Users/~/Xcode/DerivedData/~/Build/Products/Development-iphonesimulator/appname/Assets.car` (xcode11)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, bitrise

After updated Xcode from v10.x to v11.1, This error is unresolve.

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/Development-iphonesimulator/*.app/Assets.car':
1) Target 'app' (project 'app') has compile command with input '/Users/user/Desktop/app/TargetName/Images.xcassets'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'TargetName' (project 'app'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

Already, I removed Assets.car of outputFiles in Build Phases. Then, the problem is resolved temporarily till I execute command `pod install`.

But, I want **an essential solution**. Please tell me.

ps)If I do the above resolution, Bitrise execute `pod install`. So, Bitrise building test always show error.